# Extracting Data from from webpage in R

Tags: r, rvest, httr

I'm trying to pull in information from the below website. I've been working with rvest and am not making much progress. When I run html_form() no forms are found and after inspecting the elements I'm not sure where to start.

Site: https://mbn.hlb.state.mn.us/#/services/onlineEntitySearch

In a perfect world: I would search by first and last name, expand the results added below the form, and click the 'printer view' button. From here I'd write the page out to using write_xml().

Thanks!

Comment: this is not a static web page that you can easily scrape with rvest. The url you are requesting returns an html page that is essentially full of nothing but JavaScript code. The page is then built using the Angular framework. If you are very keen to automate searches on this site you may wish to consider using RSelenium to drive a browser, assuming of course, that this is within the site's terms and conditions of use.

Comment: Thank you Allan! This is exactly the insight i was looking for.